# Identifying components of mathematical models for model characterization

Tags: definition, mathematical-modeling

I am reviewing and comparing a wide range of mathematical models that are being applied to a specific realm of wildlife biology. For the comparison of these models, and to weigh advantages/disadvantages of different aspects with regard to application, I need to characterize each model. As I do not yet have a great amount of experience working with models I am unsure of essential model aspects that can be used to characterize them. Examples that I have thought of are statistical vs dynamical, linear or nonlinear, heavy or low data requirement...

Can you provide a list of aspects you would use to characterize a model, to be used for comparison?

Thank you!